# Как дать событие draggable подгруженным элементам?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, ajax, dom

Я использую jquery ui, в частности функцию `draggable` (осуществляет перетаскивание элемента мышью). У меня есть элементы, которые вставляются по средством ajax, т.е. на них событие не навешивается. А нужно, что бы у них тоже было это событие: `draggable`.
`live` в этом случае не поможет, плагин jquery.listen тоже не дал нужного результата. А еще прошу не предлагать вставлять код события в ajax запрос, это не правильно и не работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Какая каша в голове... Итак, по пунктам:

1. draggable - это не событие.
2. live() давно уже deprecated
3. Плагин никакой не нужен
4. Инициализация draggable должна быть в коде ajax-запроса, потому-что это **правильно** (и работает без нареканий)

Делается это так:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
  success: function(data) {
    $data = $(data);
    $('.elements', $data).draggable();
    $('#holder').append($data);
  }
});
```

[Можете посмотреть](http://jsfiddle.net/zhukovroman/tjTEy/1/), как динамические элементы становятся 'draggable' именно в коде функции, которая вставляет их в страницу. У вас этой функцией является функция success в коде ajax-запроса.

Comment: В этой статье http://www.linkexchanger.su/2008/73.html достаточно наглядно показано, почему нельзя вставлять draggable в код ajax запроса.

Comment: @VladimirNEW, в этой статье наглядно показано, как можно неправильно написать код :) Автор статьи криво навешивает в $.ajax.success()-обработчик на <p> и решает это всё с помощью плагина — наглядный пример bad practice. Как и читать статьи без комментариев ;) В моём ответе обработчик draggable навешивается ТОЛЬКО на элементы из AJAX-ответа.